# Sql query in Java Android

Tags: java, android, sql

I have lots of questions that I didn't find answers to.

First of all, I have two tables in MS Sql server, one is called country that contains country id and country name, and one is called family which contains country id, family id, family name and family info. The problem I am facing is how can I write a query in Java Android that gets the id of the country and compare it with the id of the country in the families table and then for each country there is its own family.

I have tried inner joins but couldn't know how to do it.

Here is my code so far:

```
 public class InsideCountries extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ArrayList<ClassListItems> itemArrayList;  //List items Array
        private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter; //Array Adapter
        private ListView listView;
        private TextView ttl;// Listview
        private boolean success = false; // boolean
        private ConnectionClass connectionClass; //Connection Class Variable

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_inside_countries);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            ttl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title) ;
            ttl.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("CountriesName"));
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvieww); //Listview Declaration
            connectionClass = new ConnectionClass(); // Connection Class Initialization
            itemArrayList = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>(); // Arraylist Initialization

            // Calling Async Task
            SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
            orderData.execute("");
        }

        // Async Task has three overrided methods,
        private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            String msg = "No Data Found";
            ProgressDialog progress;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() //Starts the progress dailog
            {
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(InsideCountries.this, "Synchronising",
                        "Please Wait...", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  // Connect to the database, write query and add items to array list
            {
                try {
                    Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN(); //Connection Object
                    if (conn == null) {
                        msg = "Please Check Your Connection";
                        success = false;
                    } else {
                        // Change below query according to your own database.

                        String query = "query here";
                            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);




                            if (rs != null) // if resultset not null, I add items to itemArraylist using class created
                            {
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                    try {
                                        itemArrayList.add(new ClassListItems(rs.getString("name")));
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                msg = "Found";
                                success = true;
                            } else {
                                msg = "No Data found!";
                                success = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                        msg = writer.toString();
                        success = false;
                    }
                    return msg;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute (String
                msg) // disimissing progress dialoge, showing error and setting up my listview
                {
                    progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(InsideCountries.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (success == false) {
                    } else {
                        try {
                            myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemArrayList, InsideCountries.this);
                            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                            listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
        {
            public class ViewHolder
            {
                TextView textName;
            }

            public List<ClassListItems> parkingList;

            public Context context;
            ArrayList<ClassListItems> arraylist;

            private MyAppAdapter(List<ClassListItems> apps, Context context)
            {
                this.parkingList = apps;
                this.context = context;
                arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>();
                arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return parkingList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
            {

                View rowView = convertView;
                ViewHolder viewHolder= null;
                if (rowView == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                // here setting up names and images
                viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName()+"");
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(InsideCountries.this,Inside_Families.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Family",parkingList.get(position).getName());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                return rowView;
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be apreciated!?

Comment: You should not be querrying ANY extenral db from Android directly.  To do so you need to include a password in your app, which makes your db totally insecure.  All access to remote dbs should occur via webservices.

Comment: Your main question is how to craft a sql statement that can pull data from multiple tables and combine them, such as a join will do. Can you provide more information about the tables, and what sql you have already tried to use? If you can get access to the database directly you can practice writing and running queries outside of code, and then put the query in your code once you've got the results you want.

Comment: Is the country id in the country table a foreign key of the country id in the family table?